# CKEditor5, why can't I see the editor plugins in the Vue 3 template?

Tags: javascript, typescript, plugins, vuejs3, ckeditor5

I defined it in Main.js.

```
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';
app.use(CKEditor).mount("#app");
```

And I used it in my component.

```
    import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

    const editorData = ref('<p>Content of the editor.</p>');
    const editor = ClassicEditor;
    console.log(editor);
    const toolbarOptions = [
        'undo', 'redo',
        '|', 'heading',
        '|', 'bold', 'italic',
        '|', 'fontSize',
        '|', 'link', 'uploadImage',
    ];

    const editorConfig = ref({
        toolbar: toolbarOptions,
    });
```

This 'ckeditor.d.ts';

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2024, CKSource Holding sp. z o.o. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or https://ckeditor.com/legal/ckeditor-oss-license
 */
import { ClassicEditor as ClassicEditorBase } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic';
import { Essentials } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials';
import { CKFinderUploadAdapter } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder';
import { Autoformat } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat';
import { Bold, Italic } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles';
import { BlockQuote } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote';
import { CKBox } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckbox';
import { CKFinder } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder';
import { EasyImage } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-easy-image';
import { Heading } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading';
import { Image, ImageCaption, ImageStyle, ImageToolbar, ImageUpload, PictureEditing } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image';
import { Indent } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent';
import { Link } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link';
import { List } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list';
import { MediaEmbed } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed';
import { Paragraph } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph';
import { PasteFromOffice } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office';
import { Table, TableToolbar } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table';
import { TextTransformation } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing';
import { CloudServices } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-cloud-services';


export default class ClassicEditor extends ClassicEditorBase {
    static builtinPlugins: (typeof TextTransformation | typeof Essentials | typeof CKFinderUploadAdapter | typeof Paragraph | typeof Heading | typeof Autoformat | typeof Bold | typeof Italic | typeof BlockQuote | typeof Image | typeof ImageCaption | typeof ImageStyle | typeof ImageToolbar | typeof ImageUpload | typeof CloudServices | typeof CKBox | typeof CKFinder | typeof EasyImage | typeof List | typeof Indent | typeof Link | typeof MediaEmbed | typeof PasteFromOffice | typeof Table | typeof TableToolbar | typeof PictureEditing)[];
    static defaultConfig: {
        toolbar: {
            items: string[];
        };
        image: {
            toolbar: string[];
        };
        table: {
            contentToolbar: string[];
        };
        language: string;
    };
}
```

Font Size is reported to be undefined. Then I installed the plugin.

`@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font`

But I didn't achieve anything. How can I configure this ?

i try;

```
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import Font from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/font';

const editor = ClassicEditor;

const toolbarOptions = [
  'undo', 'redo',
  '|', 'heading',
  '|', 'bold', 'italic',
  '|', 'mediaEmbed',
  '|', 'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor',
  '|', 'link', 'uploadImage',
];

const editorConfig = {
  toolbar: toolbarOptions,
  plugins: [Font],  // Font modülünü ekleyin
};
```

response;
ckeditor-duplicated-modules error.

Comment: Did you find solution?


I can only help you with first import  you can not import

import { ClassicEditor as ClassicEditorBase } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic';



You must import like this



import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';


But even if you import as it is in doc - you will get another errors...